# ionic pdf thumbnail viewer

Tags: pdf, ionic-framework, pdf-viewer

I want to add a pdf thumbnail to my ion-scroll view, basically I want to add something like this :

[image]

I have tried this code :

```
<iframe src="img/pdf1.pdf#view=fit,10&toolbar=0" style="width:220px;height:100%"></iframe>
        <a href="img/pdf1.pdf" class="loupe">
          <img src="img/loupe.png">
        </a>
```

This works only on web browsers not on mobiles.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open pdf in your app with scroll option, its better way to open pdf in in-app browser

Comment: No I just want a thumbnail in the top right of my page and when the click in the magnifying glass icon I open the pdf viewer in a new page